# Add Serial No. for Copy Activity to Blob

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have files in FTP and it needs to be copied to blob storage.

While copying the files to blob storage, I need to get a status of the copy activity in a table format with below details.

Let us assume we have to 3 files in FTP. Below is how I expect the output to be.

| S.No | File Name | Error Message | Copy Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | File 1 | NA | Successful |
| 2 | File 2 | NA | Successful |
| 3 | File 3 | display error message | Failed |

I tried the below.

```
{
    "name": "ABC_copy2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Initialize counter to 1 for SNo 2x",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "PH_FTP2_Dir",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "foldername": "ABC"
                        }
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "FtpReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false,
                        "useBinaryTransfer": true,
                        "disableChunking": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach_ABC",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Move to Blobs",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "FtpReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false,
                                        "useBinaryTransfer": true,
                                        "disableChunking": true
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
                                "logSettings": {
                                    "enableCopyActivityLog": true,
                                    "copyActivityLogSettings": {
                                        "logLevel": "Info",
                                        "enableReliableLogging": false
                                    },
                                    "logLocationSettings": {
                                        "linkedServiceName": {
                                            "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage_dir",
                                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                                        },
                                        "path": "dir"
                                    }
                                },
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": false,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false,
                                        "dateTimeFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "PH_FTP2_CopyActivity",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "Filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "Foldername": "ABC"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "PH_AzureStorage",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "foldername": "inputfiles-ABC"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Cpy blob Activity Success Status",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Move to Blobs",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "cpy_blob_status",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(concat('{','\"S.No\":',variables('counter'),',\"File Name\":\"',item().Name,'\",\"Copy Status to Blobs\":\"Copied Successfully\"}'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Cpy blob Activity Failure Status",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Move to Blobs",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Failed"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "cpy_blob_status",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(concat('{','\"S.No\":',variables('counter'),',\"File Name\":\"',item().Name,'\",\"Copy Status to Blobs\":\"Failed\",\"Error\":\"',activity('Move to Blobs').output.errors[0].Message,'\"}'))\n",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "increment and store in temp 2x",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Cpy blob Activity Success Status",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@string(add(int(variables('counter')),1))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "store temp to counter 2x",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "increment and store in temp 2x",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "counter",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "increment and store in temp 2x_F",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Cpy blob Activity Failure Status",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@string(add(int(variables('counter')),1))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "store temp to counter 2x_F",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "increment and store in temp 2x_F",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "counter",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Initialize counter to 1 for SNo 2x",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "counter",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set Cpy_Blob_Status_final",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach_ABC",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "cpy_blob_status_final",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@variables('cpy_blob_status')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "counter": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "cpy_blob_status": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "cpy_blob_status_final": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-08-17T08:35:26Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

But the S.No is not getting incremented [as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23NBA.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine, But I had observed from your pipeline JSON that **you didn't enabled the **Sequential**** in ForEach activity.

Make sure you check the Sequential in it.

[image]

If its not enabled, every iteration would run parallelly and they will take the first initialized value i.e, `1` and won't take the updated values from previous iterations.

So, Enabling Sequential allows the iterations to run one after another and each iteration will take the updated Serial Numbers from the previous runs(`1,2,3`).

Comment: oops, yes. thanks, it is fine now.